Usage of In ,for and within
I want to understand clearly. I saw my friend two years ago and I still remember that he was short. But, right now he has become tall. Within two years, he has grown taller. I want to express that change in a sentence.
Directly can I say,

You have grown taller within the last two years.

You have grown taller for the last two years.

You have grown taller in the last two years.



None of your texts are valid. You might say You've grown taller in the last two years.

Thank you sir@FumblesFingers

You have now edited your examples and they are correct English, but (2) is not idiomatic. The friend has presumably spent the whole of those two years gradually growing, but we wouldn't express it like that.

Thank you very much madam@Kate Bunting

Yes "You have been working in Africa for the last two years" or "You have been growing these vegetables for the last two years" would be fine because for expresses the duration of an activity (how long it took), and they've presumably not started growing two years ago and may not have stopped now.

Thank you sir, @Stuart

None of these are valid.  1, and 3 are strange and no-idiomatic (I can't work out what these mean)  2. means that he became tall two years ago and is still tall now.
The main mistake is to use "be tall" instead of "become tall".  You are also using "two years" (a length of time) instead of "the last two years". So you could say, "You have become tall in the last two years", or more idiomatically "You've grown taller in the last two years".
Again speaking literally, the person must have been tall for less than two years, so you could also say "You've been tall for less than two years."  But this is a strangely negative thing to say, and non-idiomatic.
